# Print unicode characters to terminal in utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I use Python 3.9.1 and Linux (CentOS 7). I want to print unicode characters to the console. I want to do everything in UTF-8. If I open the python interactive console and write:

`print("├")`

all goes well and it prints:

`├`

Now I put the same line `print("├")` in a file, then save the file with UTF-8 encoding (default on linux).
I then get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u251c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Where does that "latin-1" comes from ?

I also to force UTF-8 in the first line (which should be the default anyways in Python3)

```
# coding: utf8
```

but it does not change anything.

More info on what does work and what doesn't:

```
s = "├"
#print(s) # FAIL
s2 = s.encode('utf8')
print(s2) # prints b'\xe2\x94\x9c'
print(s2.decode('latin-1')) # prints the right thing
```

What is happening here? Can I get the same behavior in the script as in the interactive console?

Comment: I assume you're using Windows?

Comment: It would appear that when you run your script, it's printing into an environment that uses `latin-1` encoding? I.e. the console window in which your script runs is not using the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I don't quite understand, `print(s2.decode('latin-1'))` should NEVER print the right thing since s2 is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: @Grismar I don't know. This is the same window as the interactive python console though... How do I know that from my console?

Comment: under linux `print(s2.decode('latin-1'))` ==>  `â` for me

Comment: @MarkRansom No. Linux, CentOS 7 (through MobaXterm though, but given the fact that the error comes from the bash shell, it can't be related to windows/mobaxterm)

Comment: @JonSG You mean on your linux? For me it is ├

Comment: @Bérenger Ya, for me when I do `print(s2.decode('latin-1'))` I get `â` but I get `├` if I do just a `print(s2.decode())` or `print(s2.decode("utf-8"))` or simply `print(s)`

Comment: @JonSG with IDLE on Windows, `s2.decode('latin-1')` produces `'â\x94\x9c'`.  I guess `\x94\x9c` are unprintable characters.

Comment: What happens if you `print(u"\u251C")`, @Bérenger?

Comment: Check the value of your environment variable [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING).

Comment: @Grismar same error with the real unicode char

Comment: @MarkRansom It is not set and it works if I set it to utf8. Thanks ! Can you write an answer?

Comment: @MarkRansom But why was it not set? At what point is it supposed to be set ?

Comment: What is the `LANG` environment variable set to?

Comment: @MarkTolonen `LANG` is set to en_US

Comment: @MarkTolonen If I set it to en_US.UTF-8, it works. I put the info in an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`s = "├"` (in your UTF-8 encoded source file) assigns the character `\u251C` to the first position of `s`, a UTF-8 encoded string.

`print(s)` fails because print here ties to send the bytes representing `s` to the standard output, which expects `latin-1` encoding. Effectively, something like `s.encode('latin-1')` fails, as the first character in the string cannot be encoded correctly.

If you literally run that statement (`s.encode('latin-1')`) instead, you'll find that it causes the same error.

`s2 = s.encode('utf8')` works just fine, it tells Python to explicitly encode the contents of `s` into a sequence of bytes. `s2` now holds the byte encoding of `s`, using the UTF-8 encoding. (perhaps 'b' would have been a better variable name, it's not a string after all)

`print(s2)` does indeed print `b'\xe2\x94\x9c'`, since it simply prints the Python representation of a byte sequence. It's not a string, so you get the representation of the value printed. As it should be, it's the literal you could have used to define `s2`, i.e. `s2 = b'\xe2\x94\x9c'` wouldn't change anything.

`print(s2.decode('latin-1'))` printing the right thing is a bit of a mystery. `s2` is the correct UTF-8 byte sequence for the U+251C character (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/251c/index.htm)

Apparently your Python takes the result of `s2.decode('latin-1')`, encodes it as a `latin-1` byte sequence again, which then gets written to the output stream where it renders correctly for you.

Since Python would be doing the same for the earlier print statements trying to print a UTF-8 encoded string, it explains why those don't display correctly (or not at all).

The solution would be to tell Python explicitly to override the encoding for standard out as UTF-8, so you can print a UTF-8 string without Python trying to encode it as a `latin-1` encoding byte sequence (which will fail).

As documented here https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING you can do that by setting `SET PYTHONENCODING=UTF-8`. Conversely, if you want to replicate the problem in the interactive environment, you can probably get that behaviour with `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO`.

Where and when to set this depends on your system environment. Do other applications rely on older scripts or other versions of Python not doing this? If not, you can consider setting a global system environment variable. Alternatively, you can set it just before executing a script, i.e. in a batch file running it.

Comment: They were very clear that this was a Linux environment, so I don't think `PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO` will make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that my `LANG` environment variable was set to `en_US`, whereas it should have been `en_US.UTF-8`.

Another way to solve the problem is to set `PYTHONENCODING` to `UTF-8` (it was empty for me).

I still don't fully understand why Python is confused by this only for non-interactive scripts though...

More details: https://simulrpi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/display_problems.html

Comment: Try `import sys;print(sys.stdin.encoding,sys.stdout.encoding)` with your original `LANG` setting both at the interactive prompt and from a script  to see what encodings Python is using as default in each scenario.  You can also set `PYTHONUTF8=1` to enable the UTF-8 mode.